# set the default 'No file choosen' in file uploader instead of the image name when user tries to upload a large image

Tags: angular, image, file-upload

This is what I get when uploading an invalid image.The label upload with image name

[image: view when uploading image larger than 50kb]

below is the code in the .ts file

```
const fileSize = files[0].size;

if((fileSize / 1024) > 50) {
  this.errorMessage = '*Image size cannot exceed 50KB.';      
  return;
}

const reader = new FileReader();
this.fileName = files[0].name;
reader.onloadend = () => {
  this.userFileInfo = reader.result;
  this.imgURL = this.userFileInfo;
};
this.changeFile(files[0]).then((): any => { });
reader.readAsDataURL(files[0]);
```

}

here is the HTML code

```
 <div class="col-md-8">
       <label for="userName" class="primary-label lable-position">Profile picture</label>
       <input #file type="file" class="" accept='image/* (change)="preview(file.files)" />
 </div>
```

I want to set the label to the default value 'No file chosen' like below when uploading an invalid image

[image: view I want to get]

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried giving a style to the file uploader.

```
 element.style {
        width: 98%;
        background-color: white;
    }
```

Now it looks like below without file name.

[image: View]